# .htaccess file and different apache versions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am currently working on a project whereby I have a local WAMP stack installed running apache 2.4.4.

However the .htaccess file is built for 2.2.x. Tere is an issue with regards to some syntax in the file that on 2.4.4 kills apache.

My question is this, in .htaccess files you can do `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` cant that same kind of thing be done but based on apache version, for example run the 2.2.x code if its apache version 2.2.x or the 2.4.4 code if apache 2.4.4?

If not how would you handle the discrepancies in the different versions? I do realise i could downgrade my local apache instance, or use vagrant (can you setup vagrant to have a default apache version?)- but this would not help all developers across the company/third parties.

**EDIT**

The reason for the apache crash is the filter module, in 2.2.x the syntaxt is as follows:

```
<IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/x-icon
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
```

however in 2.4.4 the syntax is:

```
<IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/html'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/css'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/plain'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/x-component'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/javascript'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/json'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xhtml+xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/rss+xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/atom+xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/svg+xml'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/x-icon'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/x-font-ttf'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'font/opentype'"
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
```

it generates a 500 error - configuration incorrect.

Comment: I never reconized that there are any version related problems. Sure that this is not module related? And how does it crash like a dos or just a 500 error message.

Comment: i have updated the question to show the issue

Comment: After my formatting update I'm able to see the difference. I would use notepad++ to convert the syntax with regular expressions. However I'm using a phone so i cannot do that now.

Comment: yeah thats a manual way of doing it but i wasnt sure if it could be done with a simple ```<if>``` in the .htaccess file its self - which would be better.

Comment: and thanks for sorting the formatting

Comment: I googled a bit I guess the only way would be to check the server signature but however this could been disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use if version.

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4>

#do 2.4 stuff

</IfVersion>

<IfVersion < 2.3>

#do 2.2 stuff

</IfVersion>
```

EDIT - you need to have the mod_version apache module enabled to use the above

Comment: this works but please can you edit the answer to include the fact you need to have mod_version enabled.